# Double call of the useState function when the element is clicked again via onClick

Tags: reactjs, next.js, onclick

I'm trying to close a modal window when clicking on any area other than it. A window opens when I click on input, but when I click on it to close, there is a double call to useState first from my custom hook, then from input itself, please tell me how to remove this behavior?

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function useOutsideElement(initialVisible: boolean) {
   const [isShow, setIsShow] = useState<boolean>(initialVisible)
   const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

   const clickHendler = (e: MouseEvent) => {
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target as Node)) {
         setIsShow(false)
      }
   }

   useEffect(() => {
      document.addEventListener('click', clickHendler, true)
      return function () {
         document.removeEventListener('click', clickHendler, true)
      }
   })

   return { ref, isShow, setIsShow }
}
```

```
const PersonSearchBlock: NextPage = () => {
  const { ref, isShow, setIsShow } = useOutsideElement(false)
  const [adults, setAdults] = useState<number>(1)
  const [child, setChild] = useState<number>(0)
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState<number>(1)


  return (
    <div className='shelters_housing_space_container_search_bar_person'>
      <div className='shelters_housing_space_container_search_bar_person_contant'>
        <div className='shelters_housing_space_container_search_bar_person_contant_image'>
          <Image
            src={man}
            alt='человек'
            layout='fill'
            objectFit='contain'
          />
        </div>
        <input
          onClick={() => setIsShow(true)}
          type="button"
          value={
            `${adults === 1 ? `${adults} взрослый` : `${adults} взрослых`} · ${child === 0 ? 'Без детей' : child === 1 ? `${child} ребенок` : child < 5 ? `${child} ребенка` : `${child} детей`} · ${rooms === 1 ? `${rooms} номер` : rooms < 5 ? `${rooms} номера` : `${rooms} номеров`}`
          }
        />
      </div>
      {
        isShow &&
        <PersonModal
          refFunck={ref}
          adults={adults}
          child={child}
          rooms={rooms}
          setAdults={setAdults}
          setChild={setChild}
          setRooms={setRooms}
        />
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default PersonSearchBlock
```

Comment: You have added click handler on the entire body, the input included

Comment: can you tell me what exactly needs to be replaced here, otherwise I don't understand?